# Laravel 5.7: File upload form not working properly

Tags: forms, laravel-5, file-upload, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

Im having issues with a file upload in laravel 5.7
I think i have done everything correctly but the file never reaches the controller.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="{{ route('modules.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="module" type="file" class="form-control-file" name="module">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-success btn-iconText float-right">Install<i class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</i></button>
</form>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/modules', 'ModuleController@store')->name('modules.store');
```

My controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->hasFile('module'));
    dd($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('modules.index');
}
```

The hasFile()-Method  returns false. $request->all() contains the following:

```
array:2 [
  "_token" => "ceMpab3FqZU4qsHo7QTvRwKMTr2zLgc0krbcieJj"
  "module" => "example.png"
]
```

I have no idea what im doing wrong. Hopefully some can help me.

Comment: What is the size of `example.png`?

Comment: It has only 89kb, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: In php.ini file, check these variables: `file_uploads`, `upload_max_filesize` and `max_file_uploads`. Check if they are correctly configured.

Comment: all variables are configured correctly.  

file_uploads=On
  
upload_max_filesize=2MB
  
max_file_uploads=20

Comment: After a system restart its suddendly working. Sorry for wasting your time but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a system restart its suddendly working. No idea what was the problem. Mabye some browser things. Sorry for wasting your time but thanks for your help.